# The relations between the second fundamental forms of conformal immersions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $f:M^{n}\rightarrow \tilde{M}^{m}$ be an isometric immersion, that is, $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_{f}=\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the metric with respect to $M$. Also denote $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\tilde{M}}$ by the metric associeted with $\tilde{M}$.

Denote $f^{*}T\tilde{M}$ the induced bundle over $M$ whose fiber at $x \in M$ is $T_{f(x)}\tilde{M}$. The orthogonal complement of $f_{*}T_{x}M$ in $T_{f(x)}\tilde{M}$ is called the normal space of $f$ at $x$ and is denoted by $N_{f}M(x)$. The normal bundle $N_{f}M$ of $f$ is the vector subbundle of $f^{*}T\tilde{M}$ whose fiber at a point $x\in M$ is $N_{f}M(x)$. Then we have the orthogonal decomposition $$ f^{*}T\tilde{M}=f_{*}TM\oplus N_{f}M.$$ Given $X, Y$ vector fields in $M$, decompose $$ \tilde{\nabla}_{X}f_{*}Y=(\tilde{\nabla}_{X}f_{*}Y)^{T}+(\tilde{\nabla}_{X}f_{*}Y)^{\perp}.$$ As $$ \nabla_{X}Y:=f_{*}^{-1}(\tilde{\nabla}_{X}f_{*}Y)^{T}$$ defines a compatible torsion-free connection on $TM$ we have by uniqueness that $\nabla_{X}Y$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $M^{n}$. The map $\alpha:\Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(TM) \rightarrow \Gamma(N_{f}M$) defined by $$ \alpha^{f}(X,Y)=(\tilde{\nabla}_{X}f_{*}Y)^{\perp}$$ is called the second fundamental form of $f$. The shape operator $A_{\xi}$ of $f$ at $x \in M$ with repect to $\xi \in N_{f}M(x)$ is defined by $$ \langle A_{\xi}X,Y\rangle=\langle \alpha(X,Y), \xi \rangle_{\tilde{M}}.$$

> Definition: Let $f, g:M^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be immersions. We say that $f$ and $g$ are conformal, if there exists $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that the metrics induced by $f$ and $g$ are related by $$ \langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle_{g}=\varphi^{2}\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_{f}$$
>
> Problem: I would like to know if someone could show me the relations between the second fundamental forms of $f$ and $g$.

I thought of using the relation $$ \nabla_{X}^{g}{Y}=\nabla_{X}^{f}Y+\frac{1}{\varphi}(Y(\varphi)X+X(\varphi)Y-\langle X,Y \rangle_{f}\mbox{grad}_{f}\varphi)$$ where $\mbox{grad}_{f}\varphi$ is defined by $$ X(\varphi)=\langle \mbox{grad}_{f}\varphi, X \rangle_{f}.$$

Comment: The second fundamental form is not determined by the metric, as such, saying that $f$ and $g$ are conformal leaves the relation between ${II}^f$ and ${II}^g$ mostly undetermined. One can say a few limited things, though (mainly that the Weyl tensors are equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relation. Take the simplest case when $n=1$ and $m=2$. That is, $f, g$ are two immersed curves in $\mathbb R^2$. One can give both $f, g$ the arc-length parametrization, which in your notations means $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_g = \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_f$, or $\varphi = 1$. But there is no restrictions on $f$ and $g$, and so no restrictions on the curvature $\kappa$.

On the other extreme, let $f$ be any isometric immersion and let $g = f\circ h$, where $h : M \to M$ is any conformal immersion. They have the same second fundamental forms, and it has nothing to do with the conformal factor.

Comment: @Rodrigues     I'm not sure about these other answers; however the answer I was just reading is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Second_fundamental_form_of_an_immersion

Comment: picture a 2-sphere of radius a centered on the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now conformally expand a to 2a. compare the fundamental forms.

Comment: @R.Rankin The wiki you linked to answers a different question. In that page, they are changing the metric on the ambient space, but that the induced metric.

Comment: I don't quite understand your response, and apologies if I'm mistaken, I'm very new to this. Take the Gauss Codazzi equation for example in the above circumstance. Then we can relate the Riemann tensors on the ambient and immersed manifolds via the second fundamental form:

$$\tilde{R}_{xy}^{zw}=R_{xy}^{zw}+\left(h_{x}^{jz}h_{yj}^{w}-h_{y}^{zj}h_{xj}^{w}\right)$$

In general the Ricci tensor changes under a conformal transformation such that if we scale the metric on either one, doesn't the last term have to compensate? Again, sorry I'm just trying to get a grasp on this.

Comment: I've found the extrinsic stuff to be confusing after only doing intrinsic geometry for a long time.